# fastest way to change multiple loc in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 1 million rows. I want to replace values in 900,000 rows in a column by another set of values. Is there fast way to do this without a for loop (which takes me two days to complete)?

For example, look at this sample dataframe where I have condensed 1 million rows to 8 rows

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [-1,-3,-4,-4,-3, 4,5,6]
df['b'] = [23,45,67,89,0,-1, 2, 3]

L2 = [-1,-3,-4]
L5 = [9,10,11]
```

I want to replace values where `a` is -1, -3, -4 in a single shot if possible or as fast as possible without a for loop.

The crucial part is that values in `L5` have to be repeated as needed.

I have tried

```
df.loc[df.a < 0, 'a'] = L5
```

but this works only when `len(df.a.values) == len(L5)`

Comment: What is size of lists `L2` and `L3` for real data ?

Comment: Toal about 900000 rows have to be replaced. L2 and L3 sizes are about 700000

Comment: yes, then `map` is your way, please let me know how it working.

Comment: Amazing, map did it within 4 seconds. From 2 days to 4 seconds. Awesome!

Comment: Wau, it is much better how I think ;) Super :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary created from both `list`s by `zip`, last replace to original non matched values by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
d = dict(zip(L2, L5))
print (d)
{-1: 9, -3: 10, -4: 11}

df['a'] = df['a'].map(d).fillna(df['a'])
print (df)
      a   b
0   9.0  23
1  10.0  45
2  11.0  67
3  11.0  89
4  10.0   0
5   4.0  -1
6   5.0   2
7   6.0   3
```

**Performance**:

It depends of number of values for replace anf of lenght of `list`s:

Length of `list`s is `100`:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(1000, size=N)})

L2 = np.arange(100)
L5 = np.arange(100) + 10


In [336]: %timeit df['d'] = np.select([df['a'] == i for i in L2], L5, df['a'])
180 ms ± 1.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [337]: %timeit df['a'].map(dict(zip(L2, L5))).fillna(df['a'])
56.9 ms ± 2.55 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If length of lists is small (e.g. `3`):

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(100, size=N)})

L2 = np.arange(3)
L5 = np.arange(3) + 10

In [339]: %timeit df['d'] = np.select([df['a'] == i for i in L2], L5, df['a'])
11.9 ms ± 40.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [340]: %timeit df['a'].map(dict(zip(L2, L5))).fillna(df['a'])
54 ms ± 215 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) such as:

```
import numpy as np
condition = [df['a'] == i for i in L2]
df['a'] = np.select(condition, L5, df['a'])
```

and you get:

```
    a   b
0   9  23
1  10  45
2  11  67
3  11  89
4  10   0
5   4  -1
6   5   2
7   6   3
```

Timing: let's create a bigger dataframe such as with your `df`:

```
df_l = pd.concat([df]*10000)
print (df_l.shape)
(80000, 2)
```

Now some `timeit`:

```
# with map, @jezrael
d = dict(zip(L2, L5))
%timeit  df_l['a'].map(d).fillna(df_l['a'])
100 loops, best of 3: 7.71 ms per loop
# with np.select
condition = [df_l['a'] == i for i in L2]
%timeit np.select(condition, L5, df_l['a'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 350 µs per loop
```

Comment: hmmm, problem of timings is `df_l = pd.concat([df]*10000)` - large groups of values for replace, I guess in real data it should be different.

Comment: @jezrael indeed, did not think about the size of the lists used to replace

Comment: Yes, if is trap of using `pd.concat` for `timings`, same problem should be in `timings` with `groupby` - `pd.concat` create large groups.

Comment: I try create some timings too and your solution is better if small lists, I guess because `np.select` working best with small number of boolean masks.

Comment: @jezrael yes I see, I have a question about it because I copy and paste your code, and still find `np.select` faster (around 82ms) than `map` (around 154ms) for the lists of size 100. Do you know if it's because I use python 2.7 and not 3 like you probably. I read that `map`/`zip` are generator in python 3 which probably have an effect on speed? or it's something else?

Comment: Exactly, `python 3` is faster as `python 2`

Comment: @jezrael thanks, I guess it's time for me to change then :)

Comment: hmmm, it is time, check red alert http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#v0-23-0-may-15-2018